# marines with breast cancer stationed at camp lejeune from 1952-1987

Tags: data.gov

I am a marine that was stationed at camp lejeune from 1986-1988. I recently was diagnosed with breast cancer. I just want to know the total is now for marines that were there doing the contamination that has breast cancer.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with *doing the contamination* ([edit] your question)?